How to handle Spring Boot based libraries and mismatching Spring Boot versions
We are running multiple services and want to move to libraries for some common code as copy&pasting isn't working out anymore.
I do have some experience with custom spring boot starters but wanted to know how to handle a common issue I have run into in the past: diverging Spring Boot versions between libraries and services which include them.
Here is a short example:
my-library is based on SB 3.0.1
my-service is based on SB 3.0.3

Usually one would be ok with my-service implicitly forcing SB 3.0.3 but I  want to avoid this because we have run in to some nasty issues when doing this (e.g. my-librarys tests are green for SB 3.0.1 but would fail in SB 3.0.3, this would be undetected and cause a subtly broken deployment because e.g. a specific metric is not exported anymore which is specifically tested to be present in my-library - this would have recently happened to us for SB 3.0.9 in another context).
How can I configure my gradle projects to disallow two different Spring Boot Versions for such a scenario?
I was wondering if a classifier e.g. my-library:1.0.1:sb3.0.1 would work for this, but I don't know if e.g. renovate would support the needed dependency declaration: my-library:${my-lib-version}:sb${sb.version}
I am looking for an elegant way which works without manual adjustments to my build.gradle.kts for every Spring Boot version update as we maintain too many separate services for this to be viable. If possible I want to avoid any kind of custom project parent setup (like it is the case for the Maven integration of Spring Boot).

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html
By default:

Gradle will consider all requested versions, wherever they appear in the dependency graph. Out of these versions, it will select the highest one.

If your library defines a higher version and the consuming project does not define any additional constraints, then your library version would win.
But if your consuming project manages its own dependencies, which is typicaly the case for Spring Boot projects when using the Dependency Management Plugin or platforms or version catalogs, then the versions the consumer defines may win during dependency resolution.
Ultimately, you must modify each project's build to adhere to your library versions. This can be done by publishing a platform (BOM) or version catalog which then your consumers would use instead of the Spring Boot BOM for example.
So instead of, for example:
dependencies {
    implementation(platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))
}

You would do:
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("com.example:my-library-platform:1.0.0"))
}

But as you mentioned you have several projects. Tools such as OpenRewrite can help here by automating the process. Or in your CI/CD solution, you can create/define a global initialization script to customize builds.
